# I would like to know if there is another way to write this query

Tags: sql

```
SELECT orderyear, numcusts
FROM (SELECT orderyear, COUNT (DISTINCT custid) AS numcustd
        FROM (SELECT YEAR ()orderdate) AS orderyear, custid
 FROM sales,Orders) AS D1
GROUP BY orderyear) AS D2

WHERE numcusts > 70;
```

Comment: The typo aside, it is still very unlikely the query does what you want it to do. How are sales, orders and customers related? What is it you actually want to count?

Comment: Please change the query - provide data sample and required results in textual table format.

Answer (score 1):

- There is a typo in your query: `YEAR ()orderdate)` should be `YEAR (orderdate)`.
- You are doing a cross-join with an out-dated syntax: `FROM sales,Orders`. Use `FROM sales CROSS JOIN Orders` instead. But, ... do you really want a cross-join? Why would you combine all sales with all orders? It is more likely you actually want an inner join (`FROM sales INNER JOIN Orders ON ...`) or even a union of both tables.
- You can merge the two inner-most queries.
- You can get rid of the outer-most query by applying `HAVING COUNT (DISTINCT custid) > 70` directly.

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT orderyear,
           COUNT (DISTINCT custid) AS numcustd
      FROM (SELECT YEAR(orderdate) AS orderyear,
                   custid
              FROM sales,
                   Orders) AS D1
     GROUP BY orderyear
    HAVING COUNT (DISTINCT custid) > 70;
```

OR

```
    SELECT YEAR(orderdate) AS orderyear,
           COUNT(DISTINCT custid) AS numcustd
      FROM sales,
           orders
     GROUP BY YEAR(orderdate)
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT custid) > 70;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
SELECT D1.orderyear, D1.numcustd
FROM (
        SELECT YEAR(orderyear) as orderyear, COUNT (DISTINCT custid) AS numcustd
        FROM sales,Orders
        GROUP BY orderyear 
                            ) AS D1
WHERE numcusts > 70;
```